# Passing a std::vector as a pointer reference

Tags: c++

I have a function that has the following signature and which I cannot change:

```
bool function(uint8_t*& data, uint32_t size)
```

I want to pass a std vector, I am able to do it as follows:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
buffer.reserve(10);
buffer.resize(10);

uint8_t* data = &buffer[0];
function(data, buffer.size()))
```

Is there a way to avoid creating the `data` pointer? The following doesn't compile:

```
function(&buffer[0], buffer.size()))
```

gives a `no matching function` error.

Comment: `function(data, buffer.size()))` Would that pass the entire vector?

Comment: What version of c++ are you using?

Comment: @UKMonkey gcc 4.8

Comment: You need to figure out *why* the function takes a reference to a pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza haahahah company code, out of my boundaries, no access to the source code, stupid I know, I just thing it is wrong, but cannot change it

Comment: Doesn't matter. Presumably it wants to *set* a pointer you pass it. But you don't want to make `&data[0]` to point anywhere else.

Comment: @GauravSehgal it passes the address of the first element, so just like a usual C array

Comment: @juanchopanza aaaah, I understand, it could be.

Comment: @juanchopanza so with my "fix" I'm probably leaking memory, right? or not? It does work nevertheless. After that the content of the `std::vector buffer` is filled with the right data, but is the original data that it was pointing to leaked?

Comment: If there aren't comments saying what data and size are; then I would go harass someone to put comments on it so that it's a usable API; we can't guess what it wants to do with that pointer.

Comment: @UKMonkey I try every day but little by little hahaha, every thing is coded with a very old style, I need to build in top of it first hehe

Comment: @juanchopanza You solved it I think. It is a reference to a pointer, any thing that passed by an **non-const lvalue reference** can't be temporary value (i.e. you must have a variable, assign it to your value, then pass it).   In your case: `uint8_t* pass = &buffer[0];`, Then `function(pass, buffer.size()))`

Comment: @user9335240 I wasn't aware there was something to solve :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza I was just hoping for a cleaner way to do it, but fine, I'll leave it as this then. Thnx for the help!

Comment: @juanchopanza maybe write an answer summing up the discussion for future reference

Comment: @WooWapDaBug the point that was being made is that the function might change the value of data; meaning that while it might work now; you could end up with data being written outside your vector and being returned in a new pointer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that if `function` takes a reference to a pointer, it may modify it which would result in unexpected results.

If you are sure the function doesn't modify the pointer itself, you could add an overload to simplify what you want to accomplish:

```
bool function(uint8_t*& data, uint32_t size) {
    return false;
}

// overloaded on rvalue reference to pointer
bool function(uint8_t*&& data, uint32_t size) { 
    return function(data, size);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
    buffer.reserve(10);
    buffer.resize(10);
    function(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
}
```

Take into account that this is **dangerous**, especially if `function` modifies the pointer, so use with caution.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a290567fb98c072c)

Comment: how could I know if it is modifying the pointer? I think it is not, because the std::vector keeps working after it and I can loop through it with `for(auto e : buffer)`. Is this a good sign that it might not be modifying the pointer? or is it unrelated. Thanks for your solution, it's pretty neat

Comment: If you don't have access to the source or documentation, you can't really know. Writing extensive tests could help.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need this:

```
uint8_t* data = buffer.data();   // data will point to the first element of the vector
function(data, buffer.size());
// function may have modified the data pointer at this point
```

Now I would be interesting what exactly `function` does, especially if it does modify `data`.

BTW: IMO `buffer.reserve(10);` is useless as you have a `buffer.resize(10);` right after anyway.

Comment: I would be interested too, no access to the source... it basically receives a TCP message and puts the content into that buffer

Comment: If you have no access to the source, you should at least have access to some documentation.

Comment: the documentation is the header file, which has the signature I posted... hahaha just don't insists or you will make me cry, it is as I'm telling

Comment: Strange company you're working for, I hope the answers given here are helpful.

Comment: They are very helpful, and I learnt about the std::vector::data(), I was always writing &v[0] so I'm glad I asked

Comment: BTW: `vector::data` returns `nullptr` if the vector is empty